# load function does not loads all the web pages

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I am new to web dev and android and am trying to develop a web app with phone gap and also using jquery mobile for that.

I am trying to view and display my webpage within the mobile screen with headers and footers also added through jquery code.

The code which i have written to display the webpage does display for eg http://www.msn.com but when i give for eg http://46.137.... (obviously thats a incomplete address) it does not work . Bytheway the alert is shown in both the cases. Below is the code

```
<div id="cnt" data-role="content">  
    <script>
    $("#cnt").load("http://46.137....", function() {
        alert('Load was performed.');
    });
    </script>
    <!-- <iframe src="http://46.137...."></iframe>  --> 
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey @LivingThing try like this,

```
...
<div id="video1" data-role="content">
    <iframe id="cnt" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
...

<script>
   function l() {
      document.getElementById('cnt').src = "http://www.cnn.com/US/index.html"
   }
   $(window).load(function() {
      l()
      alert('Load was performed.');
   });
</script>
```

All this into `<div data-role="page">`

**I hope this helps. :)**

[image]

[image]